# how to generate fancy qr code in ionic with background img

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

I'm using the `ngx-qrcode` package for generating a qr code.
I generated the QR code but I need my QR code fancy(like color and background image)

```
  <div>
    <ngx-qrcode [qrc-element-type]="img" [qrc-value]="qrCodeString" qrc-class="test-class" qrc-errorCorrectionLevel="L"
      qrc-version="70">
    </ngx-qrcode>
  </div>
```

I want colorful QRcode with background image

Comment: <div>
    <ngx-qrcode [qrc-element-type]="img" [qrc-value]="qrCodeString" qrc-class="test-class" qrc-errorCorrectionLevel="L"
      qrc-version="70">
    </ngx-qrcode>
  </div>

Answer (score 0):

`ngx-qrcode` seems to support custom colors according to [the code](https://github.com/techiediaries/ngx-qrcode/blob/master/src/ngx-qrcode2.component.ts#L23) even though the properties are not documented. So you could change the colors like this:

```
<ngx-qrcode [qrc-element-type]="img" [qrc-value]="qrCodeString" qrc-class="test-class" qrc-errorCorrectionLevel="L" qrc-version="70"
    qrc-colorDark="#ff0000" qrc-colorLight="#0000ff"
> </ngx-qrcode>
```

There doesn't seem to be an option to set a background (or foreground) image. But you could put the QR code and an image inside a `div` with `position:relative` and absolutely position the image in front of or behind the QR code. If you want the image behind the code you also need to pass a transparent color to `qrc-colorDark` or `qrc-colorLight`, in RGBA format, e.g. `#00000000`.

Always test the code with multiple devices and apps to make sure it works. For example, I've found that some scanner apps don't work on inverted QR codes (light code on dark background).

Comment: tq so much for replying,
but I tried this for changing color but it's not working ... I found another solution for color QR is ( angular2-qrcode) .

  <div>
    <qr-code [value]="qrCodeString" [size]="150" [foreground]="'#723606'">
    </qr-code>
  </div>

Comment: now i want to add the logo for my code .how i can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
try this its 100% works .guys if you are trying to create color or fancy QR code and You are using angular or ionic,
the solution is here.
add the plugin EasyQRCodeJS.
add in HTML
“<div #qrcode>”
add in ts file
options = {
text: ‘https://www.tersesoft.com/contact-us’,
colorDark: ‘#010600’,
dotScale: ‘0.3’,
backgroundImageAlpha: ‘0.3’,
logoBackgroundColor: ‘#010600’,
backgroundImage: ‘…/…/assets/terseLogo12.png’,
PO: ‘#0320F7’,
timing_H: ‘#6274FB’,
timing_V: ‘#6274FB’,
AO: ‘#0320F7’,
};
@ViewChild(‘qrcode’, { static: false }) qrcode: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
new QRCode(this.qrcode.nativeElement, this.options);
}
```